# Gulpfile.js not showing in Task Runner

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, gulp, task-runner-explorer

We have updated to Visual Studio 2015 and our gulpfile.js is not showing in the TaskRunner window.  Our gulpfile.js is nested inside of the scripts folder, is this an issue?  If so, is there a way to work around it?

Also, our project is a web project and it is NOT nested inside of a solution folder.

Comment: If you move it to the root of the project does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work if we do that, however we don't want to do that :)